# Extinction Length calculation for Gamma Ray Photons in different materials

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation

I am having difficulty in matching ( by calculation ) some of the extinction length values reported by Filippas & Fox in their 1964 paper [Velocity of Gamma Rays from a Moving Source](http://physics.gmu.edu/%7Erubinp/courses/122/readings/apstemplate.pdf).

Filippas & Fox present the following data ( taken from [Sadeh, 1963 (restricted)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.10.271) and [Alvager et al 1963](https://doi.org/10.1038/1971191a0) ) for different photon energies and different media:-

**Table 1 Filippas & Fox reported data**

[image: Filippas & Fox reported data]

Invoking the [Extinction Theorem of Ewald & Oseen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ewald%E2%80%93Oseen_extinction_theorem) the authors state that $L$ "is the distance over which the intensity (of radiation) travelling with the velocity of the primary wave would be expected to decrease exponentially to $1/e$ of its initial value". And they present the formula:-

$$L = 1/(2N.\lambda.f(0))$$
"where $N$ is the number of scattering centres (which I assume to be electrons) per unit volume, $\lambda$ is radiation wavelength and $f(0)$ is the real part of the forward scattered amplitude. At $\gamma$-ray energies $f(0)$ is $e^2/mc^2$ the classical electron radius".

I have tried to confirm (by formulaic calculation) those reported values of $L$ and I get good agreement (within 3%) for Air with $E=0.5MeV$ and $E=4.4 MeV$. However the agreement for Lucite (62%) and Carbon (42% to 83%) is not good (see Table 2 below).

**Table 2 Calculations**

[image]

My detailed method can be inferred from Table 2, moving left to right on any particular (completed) Material&Energy combination row.  Broadly, for each combination I calculate the values of $N$ and $\lambda$ and then use the formula above to calculate $L$.  I do not know what form or density of Carbon was used by Alvager et al 1963 so I show calculations for three forms:- diamond, graphite and low-density amorphous carbon.

I have assumed that the air densities in the original experiments were as at STP.  If the actual air densities were significantly different then my calculated extinction lengths in Air would also diverge from those presented by Filippas & Fox.

I would be grateful if anyone can suggest or explain the discrepancies between reported and calculated extinction lengths.